# How to change the angle of line chart using chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

Im facing issues in changing the angle of line chart using chart.js, the chart which Im using is combination of line and bar chart together. I wanted to change the angel of it. Kindly provide your inputs on this.

Comment: @grunt Please provide your input on this

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by **change angle**? Can you perhaps share a screenshot of your expected chart *(how you want it to be)* ?

Comment: @grunt Im currently not able to add the image. I have attached the link for the same. (http://www.chartjs.org/samples/2.6.0/charts/combo-bar-line.html) In the mentioned link, I want to change the angle of blue line

Comment: @grunt Please find the attached fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/e8n4xd4z/903/) In that I need the angle of the red line to be changed it should come right side of the bar chart (i.e) It should float in air without touching the bar chart.